Android Studio Gradle errors when debugging the project
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/164d03edce25ccf673d484e810df1f53/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/16cf6b6f79cf032633ea974e72dca828/transformed/jetified-play-services-location-21.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gms.libs.identity_identity.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (48, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (75, 15): Unresolved reference: apply
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (76, 17): Unresolved reference: lockscreenVisibility
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (78, 33): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public open fun createNotificationChannel(p0: NotificationChannel): Unit defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
public open fun createNotificationChannel(p0: NotificationChannelCompat): Unit defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (86, 54): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (87, 17): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (87, 26): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (89, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (91, 14): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public open fun setSmallIcon(p0: IconCompat): NotificationCompat.Builder defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
public open fun setSmallIcon(p0: Int): NotificationCompat.Builder defined in androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (95, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (101, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (109, 33): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (115, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (118, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (120, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (124, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (169, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (172, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (173, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (193, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (194, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (196, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (201, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (203, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (214, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (215, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (216, 32): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (217, 21): Unresolved reference: it
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (227, 23): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (229, 18): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (242, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (244, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (250, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (251, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (253, 14): Class 'kotlin.Suppress' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Suppress.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (254, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (257, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (261, 33): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (264, 13): Unresolved reference: mapOf
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (264, 31): Unresolved reference: to
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (264, 63): Unresolved reference: to
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (271, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (272, 19): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (279, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (281, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (282, 25): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (283, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (285, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (286, 29): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (292, 29): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (294, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/willi/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7070922a7b5f73ff8737b4b7f5a45cc1/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (302, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-6.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (303, 69): Unresolved reference: it

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s

I have tried changing the kotlin version from 1.7.1 and 1.9.0 and 2.0.20 nothing seems to work
